# How to create private dependency method setup using Moq

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I have the following `Controller` interface:

```
public interface IInformationController
{
  string GetStoredInformation();
  string GetInformation();
}
```

The controller class is the following:

```
public class InformationController : ControllerBase, IInformationController
{
  private InformationProvider1 InformationProvider1;
  private InformationProvider2 InformationProvider2;
  private IBasicRepository repository;

  public InformationController(IBasicRepository basicRepository)  
    => repository = basicRepository;

  public string GetStoredInformation()
    => repository.GetStoredInformation();

  public string GetInformation()
    => $"Information is {informationProvider1.GetInformationHeader()}, Information detail is {informationProvider2.GetInformationDetail()}";
  
}
```

I intend to create a unit test for the `InformationController` with *xUnit and Moq*.

This is my test class:

```
public class InformationControllerTest
{
  public InformationControllerTest()
  {
    repositoryMock = new Mock<IBasicRepository>();
    repositoryMock.Setup(repository => repository.GetStoredInformation()).Returns("Stored information");
    SUT = new InformationController(repositoryMock.Object);
  }

  [Fact]
  public void GetStoredInformation_Returns_Stored_Information()
  {
    string result = SUT.GetStoredInformation();
    Assert.Equal("Stored information", result);
  }

  [Fact]
  public void GetInformation_Returns_Valid_Information()
  {
    string result = SUT.GetInformation(); //TODO: how to avoid the usage of actual provider implementations?
    Assert.Equal("Information is Header1, Information detail is Detail1", result);
  }
}
```

As you can see, there are private providers. Unfortunately they are external dependencies and can't easily be introduced via dependency injection.

How should I mock their actual calls? Should I mock the controller method (which imho should invalidate the process of testing the actual controller)? Should I try to get them via dependency injection?

Comment: How are those providers initialized or injected into the controller? It is not shown in the example provided?

Comment: The unit test is exposing the short comings of your current design. dependencies should be explicitly injected into their dependents.

Comment: My thoughts exactly, "How do I mock this private thingy?" = this class is not unit testable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unit test is exposing the short comings of your current design, which is tightly coupling to external dependencies or implementation concerns.

Dependencies should be explicitly injected into their dependents

> Methods and classes should explicitly require (typically through method parameters or constructor parameters) any collaborating objects they need in order to function correctly.

Reference [Explicit Dependencies Principle](https://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/)

```
public class InformationController : ControllerBase, IInformationController {
    private IInformationProvider1 informationProvider1;
    private IInformationProvider2 informationProvider2;
    private IBasicRepository repository;

    public InformationController(IBasicRepository basicRepository,
        IInformationProvider1 informationProvider1, 
        IInformationProvider2 informationProvider2) {
        repository = basicRepository;
        this.informationProvider1 = informationProvider1;
        this.informationProvider2 = informationProvider2
    }

    public string GetStoredInformation()
        => repository.GetStoredInformation();

    public string GetInformation()
        => $"Information is {informationProvider1.GetInformationHeader()}, Information detail is {informationProvider2.GetInformationDetail()}";
  
    //...
}
```

Create abstractions and implementations for those external dependencies, then register them with the DI container so that they can be resolved and properly provided to the controller at run-time. This will now allow them to also be tested in isolation without undesired side effects from their actual implementations.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I missed the obvious explanation :)